# Right corner at Chrome not response to mouse click

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, 23.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, the right corner does not respond to mouse clicks. The following images show three situations. The first tab is with the problem. The second, a more left tab works right. Third, after dragging the whole window to the left, the unresponsive tab starts to respond.

Clicking the x does not close the tab.

[image: the x does not close the tab]

The Chrome response to the mouse in the left tab:

[image: the chrome response to the mouse in the left tab]

Chrome response to the mouse after dragging the browser window to the left:

[image: chrome response to the mouse after dragging the browser window to the left]

Comment: Are you on xorg or wayland?

Comment: I am using wayland

Comment: I thought I was going crazy. This is EXACTLY what is happening to me. Clicking around the top right corner it randomly does not work, like something is overlapping. It is not google chrome alone. Any app that you hold and move to the right (To make it half screen) will have the issue. Files, Telegram, Sublime, VSCode, etc. .You have to drag them out of half screen mode and shrink them to be able to use their top right button again. In my case I am using Xorg

Comment: I have created a but report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2018290

Answer (score 3):

Disabling legacy app indicators fixes it as well, without uninstalling Anydesk

```
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Followed this but it did not work, so again did a system restart and then it started working. Thanks.

Comment: Yes restart is required. Also it is possible to do it via GUI - launch Extensions app, navigate to Built-In extensions, and disable "Ubuntu AppIndicators"

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue for Ubuntu 23.04, in my case any desk was the culprit. After uninstalling any desk issue was solved.

Comment: Thank you. After 1 day i fount the issue and it was anydesk. I removed this and now all are okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using anydesk on you pc / laptop.
I have face same problem.
when uninstall it then my pc is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Anydesk installed? I had the exact same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04. Applications in the top right corner of my screen would not respond to mouse-clicks. In my case I could not close or click the Firefox tabs in my upper right corner.

When I clicked there, the Anydesk window opened. Closing the Anydesk application did not help. I had to completely remove Anydesk from my system.

Answer (score 0):

Hey have exactly the same problem, But found that reducing my display resolution to 1680 x 1050 fixed the problem.
It also doesn't matter what you have open, file-manager, chromium, firefox, etc.. it's the same problem.
Noted the Anydesk app is installed and couldn't access security settings in that app either so will uninstall and further research Anydesk issues.

Answer (score 0):

Re all the above.
It turns out it's not anydesk, but whether or not you are running Wayland or Xorg...
To swap between, log out and select user.
Before entering your password you will notice a cogged wheel settings symbol.
Click it and select wayland or xorg.
Enter password and away you go.
Oh Anydesk doesn't support wayland yet.
So if you wish to continue using, you'll have to use Xorg for now.